# How to make a simple fade in/out panel with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to make a text fade in and fade out, alternately, as you click a button, using jQuery. I came up with this code:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $('#p1').fadeIn();

  $("button").click(function() {
    $('#p1').fadeOut();
    $('button').off("click");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Button</button>
<p id='p1'> Paragraph </p>
```

That works only once (fades in first click, fades out second) and the button stops working forever.

If I comment out line 5, the button works once and everytime I press it again, the text fades in and out at the same time, which is not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `fadeToggle()` which toggles between fadeIn and fadeOut.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $('#p1').fadeToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button>
<p id="p1">Paragraph</p>
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can check this on https://jsfiddle.net/kartik_bhalala/j3t01bgk/5/ this fiddle.

Comment: Your first solution solved it, but the updated version actually only works once, like mine. FTR, it wasn't me who downvoted your answer.

Comment: You can use `fadeToggle()` method for handling `fadeIn`  and `fadeOut`  automatically. You can use first solution for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could've known how to do it in the way I wanted though, because I think if I understood it, I would solve another problem I'm having with another code.

Comment: For future reference, please include the code within the question. Users shouldn't have to go off-site to understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, fadeToggle() is the way to go here.

But if I wanted to use only fadeIn and fadeOut for some reason... I solved it this way:

```
var clickCount = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
    if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
    $('#p1').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
    $('#p1').fadeOut();
    }
    clickCount++;
});
```

Comment: If you wanted to do it without `fadeToggle()`, then I'd suggest using the current state of the element instead of a count: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/w4Leqvr6/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Amazing. Thanks